# Google calendar API storing code or access token

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

Im trying to figure out Google calendars but I cant make sense out of which string I need to store in my db to fetch access tokens when I need to push or get data.

I make my request to Google and they return:

```
?code=4/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#
```

Then I authenticate:

```
$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
```

Then I get access token:

```
$client->getAccessToken()
```

Everything works great for this session. But, I dont want to have to ask the user to authenticate each time. Can I store the $_GET['code'] string and then request an access token without having the user to authenticate each time?

Thanks.

Comment: There's no point to store a code, as it is valid for short period of time and invalidates immediately after you exchange it for token. The token actually consists of two tokens: access_token (usually lives one hour) and refresh_token (long-term token). Each time you need a new valid access_token you should request Google API providing refresh_token as a proof of access. It will respond with a new access_token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely possible.

You will want to read about [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline) from the OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applicaitons. This will prevents user from your application to be prompted with the consent screen for authorization every time.

To use the 'offline access', you will need to apply the following code snippet to your app:

```
$client->setAccessType("offline");
```

You may also want to read more about the OAuth 2.0 at this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Hope it helps and Good luck!