# get refresh token in android

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have created an OAuth client ID in google console and indicating android as application type, now in my android code I get a google calendar token as follows:

```
String code = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, mScope);
```

and I want to get a refresh token because I want to stored it in my server and then get a access token when is necessary using javascript.
Can I get the refresh token with GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest?

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, String clientId, String clientSecret, String code, String redirectUri)
```

I have no clientSecret since in google console the credentials were created as android application

Comment: You should look into [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline). You can find several answers in SO. Here is [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762065/google-calendar-api-storing-code-or-access-token/33769246#33769246)

Comment: Could you show me an example? I don't understand what these parameters are: HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, String clientId, String clientSecret, String code, String redirectUri